Как закрепить плавающую кнопку во фрагменте?
У активити корневой элемент CoordinatorLayout, чтобы показывать SearchBar, а также контейнер для фрагментов FragmentContainerView. У фрагмента тоже корневой элемент CoordinatorLayout, чтобы показывать FloatingActionButton. Когда у фрагмента много текста, кнопка не закрепляется в границах экрана. Она всегда в конце текста. Тоже самое происходит если фрагмент в корне будет использовать ConstraintLayout.
Как закрепить кнопку во фрагменте? Без ее выноса в активити.
 
Активити
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
            android:id="@+id/doc_page_search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Поиск" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/hint_doc_page_search"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/doc_page_search_bar">

        <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->

    </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/doc_page_nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_doc_page_viewer" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/doc_page_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_doc_page" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Фрагмент
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markdown_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/view_indent_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/view_indent_vertical"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.BodyLarge"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@id/fab"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.FloatingActionButton.Primary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_indent_from_screen"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


По идее надо добавить вот это в FAB:
app:layout_anchor="@id/scroll_view"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" 

